# Representation of sentences in FOL

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

im trying to understand FOL and i wanted to ask if it is possible to represent the same sentence in two different ways.
i read the example of "All man drink coffee" and the representation was
∀x man(x) → drink (x, coffee).

and i wanted to ask if lets say "∀x man(x) → drinkCoffee(x)."
is a valid representation as well.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes both are valid. To be clear, you ought to enclose the entire string after "∀x" within a pair of parentheses, otherwise, strictly speaking, what you have written is equivalent to "∀y man(y) → drink (x, coffee)".